# Cannot find type definition file for ‘cordova’ : diagnostic plugin

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic3

I am unable to build my ionic 3 project after adding “Diagnostic” plugin.

There is a transpile error:

```
typescript: .....app/plugins/cordova.plugins.diagnostic/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.d.ts, line: 6
        Cannot find type definition file for 'cordova'.

   L5:  * "Dangerous" permissions that need to be requested at run-time (Android 6.0/API 23 and above)
   L6:  * See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups
   L7:  * @type {Object}
```

How can I resolve this problem? Following is the version information:

```
"@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.3",
"cordova": "^7.0.1",
"cordova-android": "6.3.0",
"cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-ios": "^4.5.3",
"ionic-angular": "^3.7.1",
```

It is working if I comment this line `/// <reference types="cordova" />` but this is not the solution i guess

Answer (score 5):

You can fix it by installing cordova types:

```
npm install @types/cordova --save
```